# How to share a Java Project with a JDBC and a SQL connection?

Tags: java, sql, swing, user-interface, jdbc

I made a french conjugator GUI using Java. I also created a SQL Database which had all the french verbs that users could pick and choose using SQL Workbench and connected it to the project.

When I tried to share it with my friends, they were able to access the Java project and see the various GUI elements, but none of the conjugations came up. I shared the database as well exported in the .sql format.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Add an in-memory database to you prroject like H2 or SQLite and insert the content of your .sql files when starting the application.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using a data base like MySql or PostgreSQL .., like that all of your friends need to install this data base into their machine and have the same configurations as yours.

- The first solution (simple) is to use an internal data base like : JavaDB,
  SqlLite .
- The second solution is to put a script that will be run within the
  first execution of you Desktop application / the installation of your
  application, this script will downloed the DB use and configure it,
  create the tables and do the Job.